# More than one value returned by subquery

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a sub query that returns more than one value.Please see the query below. There is a possibility that more than one order exist for a given customer and date. In that case I only want to return one order (It might sound strange but that is what I want to accomplish). How do I set that limit? I tried to set limit 1 in the sub query but I didn't manage to make it work?

Any ideas?

I am using Teradata

```
SELECT Person.name, 
(SELECT order FROM ORDER where
ORDER.name=Person.name AND
ORDER.date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.name=Person.name))order
FROM Person
```

Comment: (SELECT MAX(order) FROM...?

Comment: That was it. I didn't think of that max could be used in this context. If u make this the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, here's the answer:

```
SELECT Person.name, 
       (SELECT MAX(order) FROM ORDER
        where ORDER.name = Person.name
          AND ORDER.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM ORDER
                            WHERE ORDER.name = Person.name)) order
FROM Person
```

Note that both `ORDER` and `DATE` are reserved words in ANSI SQL. I suggest you double quote them to avoid future problems and improve portability. (E.g `"ORDER"`.)

Comment: `ORDER` and `DATE` are also reserved keywords in Teradata, so hopefully it was just an example and not actual column/table names :-)

Comment: That is true. :-) Since my original code had horrible names I wanted to change them to make it easier. I didn't think about this. Sorry for causing this confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ROW_NUMBER to find the latest order per name and then join it:

```
SELECT
   Person.name, 
   ORDER.order
FROM Person AS p 
LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM ORDER
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) = 1
 ) as o
ON ORDER.name=Person.name
```

Btw, this will perform much better than nested `MAX`. And it's easier to write :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Top 1 MAX(date) from you subquery, something like this

```
SELECT Person.name, 
(SELECT order FROM ORDER where
ORDER.name=Person.name AND
ORDER.date=(SELECT TOP 1 MAX(date) FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.name=Person.name))order
FROM Person
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, (SELECT MAX(o.order)
                FROM ORDER o 
                WHERE o.name = p.name 
                AND o.date= (SELECT MAX(o.date) 
                             FROM ORDER o
                             WHERE o.name = p.name))
FROM Person p
```